# xcodebuild test not running XCTestCase unit test file

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Not able to run the unit test file using `xcodebuild test -scheme DollarTests -project Dollar.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -sdk macosx`

Below is the output of the command

```
xcodebuild test -scheme DollarTests -project Dollar.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -sdk macosx
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = macosx10.9

2014-06-14 16:43:29.537 xcodebuild[3504:92734] stream error: stream error at offset 29: created by an unsupported XCDependencyGraph build
2014-06-14 16:43:29.540 xcodebuild[3504:92735] stream error: stream error at offset 29: created by an unsupported XCDependencyGraph build
=== BUILD TARGET Dollar OF PROJECT Dollar WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ankur/Personal/Dollar/Dollar/Dollar.swift' of type text for architecture x86_64
OS X deployment target '10.10' for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '10.9' for the OS X 10.9 SDK.

=== BUILD TARGET DollarTests OF PROJECT Dollar WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ankur/Personal/Dollar/DollarTests/DollarTests.swift' of type text for architecture x86_64
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ankur/Personal/Dollar/DollarTests/CarExample.swift' of type text for architecture x86_64
OS X deployment target '10.10' for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '10.9' for the OS X 10.9 SDK.

Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2014-06-14 20:43:30 +0000
Test Suite 'All tests' finished at 2014-06-14 20:43:30 +0000.
Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.001) seconds
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

For some reason it is not able to pick up the XCTestCase files and I get the following warning

```
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ankur/Personal/Dollar/DollarTests/DollarTests.swift' of type text for architecture x86_64
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/ankur/Personal/Dollar/DollarTests/CarExample.swift' of type text for architecture x86_64
```

The test files are in Swift, so it that the issue and how can I resolve it to include these and run these file when running test.

Attaching screenshots of the configuration and files I have in the project

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably wont help by try to run `clean test`. Furthermore, does it matter: `OS X deployment target '10.10' for architecture 'x86_64' and variant 'normal' is greater than the maximum value '10.9' for the OS X 10.9 SDK.`?

Comment: I tried clean and that did not help. If I run the Test using Command + U in the keyboard it runs the test file correctly and all test are passing so if someone knows how I can find out what command is being run under Command + U I can run that on the console.

Comment: What version of `xcode` are You using? I'm afraid that that there's now way to know what command is run under the hood.

Comment: xcode 6 Beta but I run the same command on Travis CI https://travis-ci.org/ankurp/Dollar.swift/builds/27613897 and it doesnt run the test either

Comment: This mobile or desktop app?

Comment: Its library code that will work on both Mac OS X and iOS

Comment: Hmm.. I suppose I need to fetch the project and try. Won't do it until tomorrow unfortunately.

Comment: On my workstation it works perfectly fine (despite the fact that it's all very, very slow). Command I run `xcodebuild -scheme DollarTests -project Dollar.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -sdk macosx test` works with `clean` and without it. I also changed the asserts in tests to be sure it it fails. It behaves well. The only problem was that `DollarTests` wasn't configured for running - it can be changed in scheme settings. Xcodebuild version: `Xcode 6.0 Build version 6A215l`.  OS 10.9.3. Can I help somehow?

Comment: Have You solved the problem?

Comment: @Opal Not really. I still cant get it to run tests on my Mac using Xcode Beta 2 and Travis CI

Comment: Difficult to help in this case, unfortunately :/

Comment: I still get the error even after verifying that my version of xcodebuild (6.2 6C131e) is correct with respect to the version set in Xcode. Could be related to the fact that I also have Xcode 6.3 (6D532l) installed, but my command line tools are still being set to the latest 6.2 GM release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same problem when building my project from the command line. The problem is likely that the command line tools are configured to use a version prior to Xcode 6. This was the case with my configuration.

In my case I ran

> xcodebuild -version

and it returned the following:

> Xcode 5.1.1
>   Build version 5B1008

So then I went to Xcode Preferences as show below and picked the version 6 command line tools and the problem went away.

[image]

After that you can confirm the command line tools version by using

> xcodebuild -version

and you should get back

> Xcode 6.0
>   Build version 6A267n

or a similar value depending on which beta you currently have installed.

Comment: You may also want to try xcode-select. It allows you to switch the directories for developer tools. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html